# Show progress dialog while inserting record into database in Android

Tags: android

i tried to show a progress dilog while inserting 3000 records into the data base but i dont know where to place it in my code
this is my main activity

```
public class Screen1 extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */


    private SQLiteAdapter mySQLiteAdapter;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

         setContentView(R.layout.s1);

         Button gas = (Button) findViewById(R.id.gas);

         mySQLiteAdapter = new SQLiteAdapter(this);
            mySQLiteAdapter.openToWrite();
           // mySQLiteAdapter.deleteAll();


            Cursor cur = mySQLiteAdapter.isempty();
            if (cur != null){
                cur.moveToFirst();
                if (cur.getInt(0) == 0) {




                    mySQLiteAdapter.insert("AUDI","A4","2001","MUMTAZ");
                    mySQLiteAdapter.insert("AUDI","A4","2002","MUMTAZ");
                    mySQLiteAdapter.insert("AUDI","A4","2003","MUMTAZ");
                    mySQLiteAdapter.insert("AUDI","A4","2004","MUMTAZ");
                    mySQLiteAdapter.insert("AUDI","A4","2005","MUMTAZ");
                    mySQLiteAdapter.insert("AUDI","A4","2006","MUMTAZ");
                    mySQLiteAdapter.insert("AUDI","A4","2007","MUMTAZ");
                    mySQLiteAdapter.insert("AUDI","A4","2008","MUMTAZ");
                    mySQLiteAdapter.insert("AUDI","A4","2009","MUMTAZ");
                    mySQLiteAdapter.insert("AUDI","A4","2010","MUMTAZ");
                    mySQLiteAdapter.insert("AUDI","A4","2011","MUMTAZ");

                    mySQLiteAdapter.insert("AUDI","A5","2001","MUMTAZ");
                    mySQLiteAdapter.insert("AUDI","A5","2002","MUMTAZ");


// and other 3000 records


}
//close database
```

and this is the db file:

```
public class SQLiteAdapter {

    //
    // Databsae Related Constants
    //
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "car";
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "options";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    public static final String KEY_MANUFACTURER = "manufacturer";
    public static final String KEY_MODEL = "model";
    public static final String KEY_YEAR = "year"; 
    public static final String KEY_TYPE = "type"; 
    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";



    private SQLiteHelper sqLiteHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;


    /**
     * Database creation SQL statement
     */
    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
            "create table " + DATABASE_TABLE + " ("
                    + KEY_ROWID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
                    + KEY_MANUFACTURER + " text not null, " 
                    + KEY_MODEL + " text not null, "
                    + KEY_YEAR + " text not null, " 
                    + KEY_TYPE + " text not null);"; 



    private Context context;

    public class SQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        public SQLiteHelper(Context context, String name,
                CursorFactory factory, int version) {
            super(context, name, factory, version);
        }


        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
        }






    }


    public SQLiteAdapter(Context c){
        context = c;
    }



    public long insert(String manufcturar, String model, String year ,String type) {
        ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
        initialValues.put(KEY_MANUFACTURER, manufcturar);
        initialValues.put(KEY_MODEL, model);
        initialValues.put(KEY_YEAR, year); 
        initialValues.put(KEY_TYPE, type);
        return sqLiteDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
    }
```

Comment: use an asynctask. see tutorials at android developer site.

Answer (score 1):

You need to run your data base update in a worker thread and publish progress on the UI thread. The tool to use for this is [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). The class documentation has some sample code and there's more to be found in the guide topic [Processes and Threads](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/processes-and-threads.html) and in the [Painless Threading](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html) article. The last link is the easiest place to start reading.

Answer (score 0):

right before you run the db Script, you can show the busy/progress icon and make it dissaper after the execution of the code.

```
cur.moveToFirst(); //right before this line enable the progressbar
if (cur.getInt(0) == 0)

{
//Insert
}

//finish
```

Comment: This will not work. The data base updates are blocking the UI thread; the progress bar won't show until `onCreate` returns.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use AsyncTask.
In your Activity:

```
    private static final int PROGRESS_DIALOG_ID = 0;

    .....

    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        if (id == PROGRESS_DIALOG_ID) {
           ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
           dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
           dialog.setMessage("Loading...");
           dialog.setCancelable(false);
           return dialog;
        } 
    }  

    ........ 

    class SomeTask extens AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            showDialog(PROGRESS_DIALOG_ID);
        }

        @Override
        protected void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            //fill your database
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void voids) {
           dismissDialog(PROGRESS_DIALOG_ID);
        }

    }
```

Comment: class SomeTask extens AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() { ....   shuold i put in the same activity or in other java file

Comment: Yes put it in your activity, and call new SomeTask().execute();

Comment: i have done that put there is one error Syntax error on tokens, AnnotationName expected instead in the biginning of the class

Comment: there is an error with the number of insert :The code of method doInBackground(Void...) is exceeding the 65535 bytes limit